# Bootstrap 4 row not expanding to 100% width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to make a row that will contain 3 columns. One for the pagination count, one to filter a table, and another to hold a button.

Everything looks great in small, medium and large viewports, but when I maximize my window, there is a huge gap on the right above my table. See image below (bottom) for reference.

[image]

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've tried every variation of flex-fill, w-100, etc. that I can think of to get it to expand to 100% width on xl viewports, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the relevant code for that section that sits above the table:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="container no-padding">
        <div class="row mt-1">
            <div class="col d-none d-md-block no-padding">
                <p>Showing {{ $assets->firstItem() }}-{{ $assets->lastItem() }} of {{ $assets->total() }} total</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto flex-fill flex-md-grow-0 no-padding mb-3">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col m-0 p-0 mr-2">
                            <form class="form-inline">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input style="font-size:80%;" class="form-control" type="text" name="filter" value="" placeholder="Filter results">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="no-padding">
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm mr-1" href="{{ action('AddAssetController@index') }}" role="button"><i style="font-size:80%;" class="fas fa-plus"></i> New Asset</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

Here's the code from my template. Code above is part of `@section('content')` which gets output to and parsed by `@yield('content')` below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 no-padding">
        @include('layout.includes.header')
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-12">
        <!-- Begin nav/content row --> 
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="visible">
                @include('layout.includes.nav')
            </div>
            <!-- Begin main column -->
            <div class="col content" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                <div class="row no-padding">
                    <div class="col d-none d-sm-block">
                        <h4>@yield('content-heading')</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col flex-grow-1">
                        @include('layout.includes.searchform')
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row no-padding inner-box shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                    @yield('content') <!--this is where the original code appears-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END main column-->
        </div>
        <!-- END nav/content row-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think this gap is actually the margin of the container, this get a bit messy

Comment: Could you include some more code. I want to see what you have the first col inside of. I also see a row with 2 col and one of those columns contains a container with another row.

Comment: @EdwinCruz see my edit above. Any assistance would be great.

Comment: @LeandroRR can you elaborate?

Comment: Why are you putting containers in some of the columns?

Comment: I honestly thought that was the correct method. I have taken out all containers and it fixed the issue. I can't believe it was that easy. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want achieve but, i tried my best to make it look like what you desire, let me know if is really this: https://jsfiddle.net/leandrorr/t4rbfdv3/6/

html:

```
<div class="result-count p-4 border">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        Showing 1-20 of 32 total
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form action="" class="form-inline float-right">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```